# Force DNS to attach bad IP address

Tags: attacks, attack-prevention, dns, injection, dns-domain

The question is not professional, but what I'm trying to say is...

Is there any way to inject or force the DNS server to attach/change an IP address for some site. For example, I'm running an apache on my machine and I have my sniffing website on it. I'd like to know how to attack the DNS which is going through port 53 on my gateway, so it will change the IP address for www.example.com to my local IP address and everyone from the local network that I'm connected to will be redirected to my machine when they type www.example.com

I'm not asking for every step of this attack, just some info and maybe the name of attack like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Kaminsky attack](http://spectrum.ieee.org/images/oct08/images/phish03.pdf) is a technique with which you can flood the DNS recursive server (like your gateway) with DNS replies that ultimately match the response that the recursive server is originally looking for. This is also called DNS cache poisoning.

An alternate technique would be to ARP-spoof your IP as the gateway and let everyone make the DNS query to a DNS server running on your machine. Your rogue DNS server can then reply with the forged DNS records.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I wanted to know :)

Comment: Well done on you're answer, could not had put it better.